# Best http request headers for the api key of upstream services?

Tags: http, http-headers, request-headers

I have a gateway server connected with some upstream services which handles important resources. I want the client call the gateway server with the api key for using the upstream services. That is, there are two confidential information, one for the gateway server and one for the upstream servers.

What is the best http request headers for passing the the upstream servers' credentials?

I will use `Proxy-Authorization` header for authenticating requests to the gateway server. However, I want to know good headers for authenticating requests to the upstream servers.

Thanks in advance.